# git clone of git itself creates Git dir which is hardlinked to git

Tags: git

The command "git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git" clones git into a directory named git, as I expected.  I did not expect to find a directory named Git at the same level, hardlinked to git.

Why did it do that?

Comment: What OS/filesystem are you using that supports hardlinked directory entries?

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like git, so I cloned a git into your git so you can git while you git. (Sorry, it was too easy)

Comment: Greg: I'm using OS X, which supports hardlinked directories because Time Machine uses them. Both git and Git have the same inode and removing either one removes both.

Comment: Well that's pretty unexpected. I cloned that same repo and only got a `git` directory, as expected. (I'm on 10.4, which I think was pre-Time-Machine, and in any case doesn't seem to support directory hard links with `ln`.)

Comment: Are you on case-insensitive HFS+, or some other filesystem?

Comment: I'm on 10.6.6 and did not get a "Git" dir when I cloned

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Git didn't create that directory; something else must have, or you misinterpreted some command output.  Posting some more information might help.  How about:

```
rm -rf git Git
ls -li
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git
ls -li
```

<strike>Just to clarify, it's not possible to hardlink two directories on OS X (or most systems).</strike>  **Edit:** Huh, you're right, Time Machine does create directory hard links. OS X's weird file system features are most fascinating. ^^